# Hibernate oneToMany gets ignored

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I have a domain object T which has a oneToMany relationship with another domain object pTW. This is the code in my class T

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "t")
@OrderBy("dateRequested desc")
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_t_ptw")
private final List<PTW> pTWList = new ArrayList<PTW>();
```

The problem is that when I update, delete or insert T, all the information in pTW gets ignored. The problem does not happen for other type of relationships. The annotation @OneToMany belongs to the javax.persistence package. Logs do not show any problem at all.

My gut feeling is that there might be some conflicts or issues with the jar files. This is what I get for Hibernate when I run mvn:dependency:tree :

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:jar:4.0.0-CR1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:jtidy:jar:r8-20060801:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.8.0.v_C03:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse:text:jar:3.2.0-v20060605-1400:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.core:commands:jar:3.3.0-I20070605-0010:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.equinox:common:jar:3.2.0-v20060603:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.2.0-v20060603:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse:osgi:jar:3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.core:jobs:jar:3.3.0-v20070423:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.equinox:registry:jar:3.3.0-v20070522:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:jar:3.2.100-v20070522:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.core:contenttype:jar:3.2.100-v20070319:runtime
```

Has anyone experienced the same problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency:tree looks ok to me, but your @OneToMany doesn't. You should have a @ManyToOne on PTW and if you explicitly specify JoinColumn that's where it should be:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "T_ID")
private T t;
```

T on the other hand should carry the @OneToMany and designate the join column using "mappedBy"

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="t", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<PTW> pTWList = new ArrayList<PTW>();
```

Comment: The way the relationships are coded is far from being ideal (I have inherited this project!). I recoded that particular relationship in a more "traditional" way, that is the way you suggested. Unfortunately the problem is still there. Thanks for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted.

First mistake. The developer which I inherited the project from did commit in svn some database changes needed for auditing purposes in svn. 
Second mistake. The auditing framework ignores any error. It just rolls back the failing transaction and writes a warning message in the log file, not even an error message, a warning!

Nothing to do with Hibernate or maven or anything technically interesting. Thanks again to wallenborn for his contribution.